# LegacyIAccessible in Windows.Automation

Tags: c#, winapi, automation

How to obtain  LegacyIAccessible.State and others LegacyIAccessibles of AutomationElement with C# ?
just like Inspect.exe from tools makes it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LegacyIAccessible` is new and is not available in the .NET level as is in .NET 4.0. But there is a [project on CodePlex](http://uiacomwrapper.codeplex.com/) that has a newer implementation that in [change set 38718](http://uiacomwrapper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/38718#) added support for this.

Be beware that you have to compile the project from source, the latest binary release is too old to contain this unfortunately...

What you want to do is something like:

```
if ((bool) child.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElementIdentifiers.IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailableProperty)) {
    var pattern = ((LegacyIAccessiblePattern) child.GetCurrentPattern(LegacyIAccessiblePattern.Pattern));
    var state = pattern.GetIAccessible().accState;

    // Do something with state...
}
```

The comments in the source code says that these are new features for Windows 7, but I get it to work on Windows XP SP3...

Hope this helps!

/AZ

Comment: But would not conflict with .net4? It has own implementation of .  I am newbie in C#. Can I use only LegacyIAccessiblePattern.cs  from that project or from http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: I tried lib from uiautomationverify and pattern.GetIAccessible() returns null :(

Comment: No it does not conflict with .NET 4 - you can replace the assembly with the code from the one you build. It has the same interface (or, really a superset) so it should work fine.

Comment: @AndersZommarin: It works. Now I can use this to call DoDefaultAction on the control :) Thanks a lot. You save my life !!!

Comment: @Hoang-Minh: Great! Glad to be able to help some!