# Can UI Automation access every LegacyIAccessible Property? (inspect.exe)

Tags: accessibility, inspect, microsoft-ui-automation

looking at inspect.exe there are several properties like

```
HelpText:   "Press to see all available devices"
ClickablePoint: {x:500 y:400}
Orientation:    0
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:  0
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:    "Expand"
LegacyIAccessible.Description:  ""
LegacyIAccessible.Help: "Press to see all available devices"
```

I would like to know, if the **HelpText-Prop** can **differ** from the **LegacyIAccessible.Help-Prop** somehow? (maybe in special cases?!) Furthermore it is interesting to me, **if every LegacyIAccessible-Prop is available via UI Automation for 100%?**
cheers

Comment: Please refer the below link. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837935/legacyiaccessible-in-windows-automation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa